# LineNumbering or Incrementing Counter on XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I'm sure this has been asked before, and I'm just not searching with the right criteria, or I've been looking at this too long and can't see the wood for the trees.

Basically whislt not new to XML/XSL Transformations, it's not a big part of my role, I have an XSL transformation that converts the XML from a Microsoft SSRS report into a formatted text file, and what I'm trying to do is calculate linenumbering to force pagebreaks in the right places:

Here's a sample of my XML output from SSRS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report  Name="GR_ItemSample.srdl" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="GR_ItemSample.srdl">

    <Item Detail_ItemCode="6407" Detail_Description="SOLU-CORTEF INJ.SOL.250MG ACT-" Detail_UnitOfSale="AOV" Detail_Quantity="1" Detail_UnitPrice="0,00" Detail_Gross="0,00" Detail_Discount1Percentage="0,00" Detail_Discount1Amount="0,00" Detail_Discount2Percentage="0,00" Detail_Discount2Amount="0,00" Detail_Discount3Percentage="0,00" Detail_Discount3Amount="0,00" Detail_Net="0,00" Detail_Lot="TEST123" Detail_VatPercentage="0,0" Detail_MiscDesc2="*** This is a second line description test *******" valueOnlyIdentifier="1" />
    <Item Detail_ItemCode="6407" Detail_Description="SOLU-CORTEF INJ.SOL.250MG ACT-" Detail_UnitOfSale="AOV" Detail_Quantity="1" Detail_UnitPrice="0,00" Detail_Gross="0,00" Detail_Discount1Percentage="0,00" Detail_Discount1Amount="0,00" Detail_Discount2Percentage="0,00" Detail_Discount2Amount="0,00" Detail_Discount3Percentage="0,00" Detail_Discount3Amount="0,00" Detail_Net="0,00" Detail_Lot="TEST123" Detail_VatPercentage="0,0" Detail_MiscDesc2="" valueOnlyIdentifier="1" />
    <Item Detail_ItemCode="6407" Detail_Description="SOLU-CORTEF INJ.SOL.250MG ACT-" Detail_UnitOfSale="AOV" Detail_Quantity="1" Detail_UnitPrice="0,00" Detail_Gross="0,00" Detail_Discount1Percentage="0,00" Detail_Discount1Amount="0,00" Detail_Discount2Percentage="0,00" Detail_Discount2Amount="0,00" Detail_Discount3Percentage="0,00" Detail_Discount3Amount="0,00" Detail_Net="0,00" Detail_Lot="TEST123" Detail_VatPercentage="0,0" Detail_MiscDesc2="*** This is a second line description test *******" valueOnlyIdentifier="1" />
    <Item Detail_ItemCode="6407" Detail_Description="SOLU-CORTEF INJ.SOL.250MG ACT-" Detail_UnitOfSale="AOV" Detail_Quantity="1" Detail_UnitPrice="0,00" Detail_Gross="0,00" Detail_Discount1Percentage="0,00" Detail_Discount1Amount="0,00" Detail_Discount2Percentage="0,00" Detail_Discount2Amount="0,00" Detail_Discount3Percentage="0,00" Detail_Discount3Amount="0,00" Detail_Net="0,00" Detail_Lot="TEST123" Detail_VatPercentage="0,0" Detail_MiscDesc2="" valueOnlyIdentifier="1" />
    <Item Detail_ItemCode="6407" Detail_Description="SOLU-CORTEF INJ.SOL.250MG ACT-" Detail_UnitOfSale="AOV" Detail_Quantity="1" Detail_UnitPrice="0,00" Detail_Gross="0,00" Detail_Discount1Percentage="0,00" Detail_Discount1Amount="0,00" Detail_Discount2Percentage="0,00" Detail_Discount2Amount="0,00" Detail_Discount3Percentage="0,00" Detail_Discount3Amount="0,00" Detail_Net="0,00" Detail_Lot="TEST123" Detail_VatPercentage="0,0" Detail_MiscDesc2="*** This is a second line description test *******" valueOnlyIdentifier="1" />
</Report>
```

and here is my sample xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:rpt="GR_ItemSample.srdl">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="utf-8" media-type="text/plain"/> 
<xsl:template match="rpt:Report">
    <xsl:variable name="CrLf1" select="'&#13;&#10;'"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="rpt:Item">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(),' - ',@Detail_ItemCode,@Detail_Description,@Detail_UnitOfSale,@Detail_Quantity,@Detail_UnitPrice,@Detail_Gross,@Detail_Discount1Percentage,@Detail_Discount1Amount,@Detail_Discount2Percentage,@Detail_Discount2Amount,@Detail_Discount3Percentage,@Detail_Discount3Amount,@Detail_Net,@Detail_Lot,@Detail_VatPercentage,$CrLf1)"/> 
        <xsl:if test="string-length(@Detail_MiscDesc2) > 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(),' - ',@Detail_MiscDesc2,$CrLf1)"/>              
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now when I run the transformation I get the following output, which is close to what I want:

```
1 - 6407SOLU-CORTEF INJ.SOL.250MG ACT-AOV10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,00TEST1230,0
1 - *** This is a second line description test *******
2 - 6407SOLU-CORTEF INJ.SOL.250MG ACT-AOV10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,00TEST1230,0
3 - 6407SOLU-CORTEF INJ.SOL.250MG ACT-AOV10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,00TEST1230,0
3 - *** This is a second line description test *******
4 - 6407SOLU-CORTEF INJ.SOL.250MG ACT-AOV10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,00TEST1230,0
5 - 6407SOLU-CORTEF INJ.SOL.250MG ACT-AOV10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,00TEST1230,0
5 - *** This is a second line description test *******
```

I'm using position() to display the "line number" within my for-each loop, now when I had just one line to print in the text file for each line this was perfect, however a new requirement to add a second description line has been requested, this second description line appears on the same item line as @Detail_MiscDesc2, but it has to appear on the next line down in the Text file output, which my xsl does conditionally based on the string-length of @Detail_MiscDesc2, however I need to know the cumulative line numbers at this point, so my sample output should actually look like:

```
1 - 6407SOLU-CORTEF INJ.SOL.250MG ACT-AOV10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,00TEST1230,0
2 - *** This is a second line description test *******
3 - 6407SOLU-CORTEF INJ.SOL.250MG ACT-AOV10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,00TEST1230,0
4 - 6407SOLU-CORTEF INJ.SOL.250MG ACT-AOV10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,00TEST1230,0
5 - *** This is a second line description test *******
6 - 6407SOLU-CORTEF INJ.SOL.250MG ACT-AOV10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,00TEST1230,0
7 - 6407SOLU-CORTEF INJ.SOL.250MG ACT-AOV10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,00TEST1230,0
8 - *** This is a second line description test *******
```

I need this because I also have to calculate page breaks and headers and footers, I know that for my stationary I can only have 22 detail lines per page in total. I don't actually need to print the line numbers (thats just for this sample) I simply need to know when I've reached 22 lines so I can process footers and pagebreak. I'm much more used to procedural programming languages where this would be dead easy. I know I can't use position() for this and need to use a recursive-template, but I just can't get my head around how to do it. Any assistance or pointers would be greatly appreciated.
I've tried to give as much detail as possible without getting too long-winded (yea I know failed there!) but if anything is not clear please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of printing `position()`, you could print the `count()` of preceding Items, plus the count of preceding Items with a description that forces a second line. Something like:

```
count(preceding-sibling::*) + count(preceding-sibling::*[string-length(@Detail_Misc2) &gt; 0])
```

Comment: I had to add a +1 to each count to get it to start at 1 rather than 0, that then got me the answer I was expecting of 8 (ie eight lines). I looked at preceding-sibling but couldn't figure out how to get it to work for me. Definitely been looking at this a bit too long me thinks, thanks that sample code sorted me out a treat.